# Why doesn't the Chattan say the bracha for Kiddushin?

Tags: blessing, kiddushin-eirusin

If Kiddushin is a mitzvah that applies to the chattan only, and the 1st bracha recited under the chuppah (besides the bracha for wine) is a bracha prior to the performance of the mitzvah of Kiddushin, then why isn't the Chatan the person making this bracha? (At least, I have never seen this done at any wedding that I have attended.)

Furthermore, there is a rule that for someone to *motzi* someone else of a birkat hamitzvah, the person making the bracha must have the same mitzvah obligation. Here, this is clearly not the case. So, how can anyone else make this bracha?

Comment: The Chattan used to say it, but due to people not knowing the blessing, the custom beame that the Mesader Kidushin says it (sort of like how a Bal Korei reads the Torah for the person getting an Aliyah).

Comment: @Salmononius2, in other words, a chattan who knows to say it should ?

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt The premise of my question is greater than that. Based on my assumptions, the Chattan is the only one who can do it and he **must** do it. If he can't read Hebrew, than, perhaps, no bracha should be made. Of course, this assumes that it is a birkat hamitzvah and not some other category.

Comment: "the person making the bracha must have the same mitzvah obligation" this is not true. One who already read megillah can say the blessings for someone else who is hearing it now. He just needs to be generally in the category of those who are obligated in Megillah

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes, you are more precise. However, with Megillah, Kiddush, etc. the person had the obligation at some point. That's not the case, here.

Comment: It is the same here! The mesadder kiddushin is as able as the groom to effect Kiddushin. They're in the same boat. They have the same level of obligation in whatever mitzva is happening under the chuppah. It's just like a saying a blessing on megillah for someone else.

Comment: @DoubleAA how about a mesader kiddushin who's related to the bride (is that allowed)?  He can effect kiddushin in general but not on her.

Comment: @heshy ya I thought of that and clearly the answer is it doesn't matter, but how to say that lumdishly is interesting. Probably similar to me saying a blessing for you to shake your lulav. I can't shake your lulav,but I can shake lulavs

Comment: @salmon not everyone agrees to that reasoning

Comment: Maybe the custom is based on the opinion that it's a birkas hashevach

Comment: See http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x7203

Comment: You might want to cite your first paragraph as being predicated on Rambam, Ishus 1:1-2 and 3:23-24, which make clear that there is such an opinion that Kiddushin is a Mitzvah and that the Beracha in question is actually a Birchas HaMitzvah, both points disputed by the Rosh, Kesuvos 1:12.

Comment: @DonielF If you're citing Ramba"m and others stating " the Beracha in question is actually a Birchas HaMitzvah", it seems that may be part of the answer which allows others to say this bracha.

Comment: @DanF I didn’t provide any information other than what’s already in your question; merely a source for it. You already presuppose this is a Birchas HaMitzvah in your statements “And the 1st beracha recited under the chuppah...is a bracha prior to the performance of the Mitzvah of Kiddushin” and “There is a rule that for someone to *motzi* someone else of a birkat hamitzvah.”

Comment: @DonielF Understood. But, I also have no problem with my assumption being refuted.

Answer (score 3):

Although the Chattan should recite the Berachot, as it’s his Mitzvah to get married and start a family, usually, the Mesader Kiddushin recites the Berachot, so as not to embarrass Chattanim who don’t know how to do it themselves. (Rama and Perisha Even HaEzer 34:1)

Since the Rambam holds that it’s a Birkat HaMitzvah, the Chattan should ideally appoint the Mesader Kiddushin as his messenger to say the Beracha in his place, as it’s his Mitzvah to marry this woman. (Yalkut Yosef, Sova Semachot 6:16)

Rav Meir Mazuz (Bayit Ne’eman vol. 1 Even HaEzer 3:10) asserts that the old Minhag in North Africa and in modern day Djerba was for the Chattan to recite the Berachot himself. Doing so allows Halachic concerns of Beracha Levatalah to be avoided and is certainly possible at any wedding in Israel nowadays.

Rav Eliyahu Ben-Haim in YU does sometimes recommend following the Rambam Kepeshuto also, but he defers when the appointed Mesader Kiddushin is a renowned Talmid Chacham. Giving the Kavod of Birkat Erusin to the Talmid Chacham was more valuable to him.

I heard Rav Eliyahu Bar Shalom elaborate the embarrassment point as follows: the Kallah thinks that her husband is the best guy in the world. It would be demeaning for the chattan in *her* eyes if he botched this beracha.

Regarding your last point, Shomea KeOneh works as long as one is betorat chuppah vekiddushin, which the Mesader Kiddushin is.

See further in [Sdei Chemed (Chattan veKallah 18)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=53079&st=&pgnum=55).

Comment: I would just add a few points mentioned in the haaros on the Yalkut Yosef page .140: haara 16 ,which brings from teshuvos HaRambam that in his days the gedolim made the bracha,he also brings  opinions which hold that the chassan should make the bracha (The Smak 183,The Smag,Rabbeinu Yecheil)

Comment: The Rama doesn't say that and not everyone agrees with the perisha. There's some interesting stuff here, but the main points are very lacking.

Comment: @DoubleAA Please elaborate on what is lacking. I don't see it.

Comment: @danf Fuller discussion of your question "Why doesn't the Chattan say the bracha for Kiddushin?"

Comment: @DoubleAA ,well according to Chacham Ovaida it is because not to embarrass one who doesnt know,and because one might mess up because they are nervous.

Comment: @sam that could be fine as one opinion (though he isn't cited here) but there's more to the sugya than one opinion.

Comment: That is true,if I have time I will write an answer with both sides,unless you get to it first

Answer (score -1):

> (At least, I have never seen this done at any wedding that I have attended.)

Actually, I've been to a Temani wedding (with an Ashkenazi bride) and the Chattan did make the brachot of Kidushin.

<sup>I no longer recall if he said all the 7 brachot afterwards, but I don't think so.</sup>

Comment: That's very interesting, seems like they hold like the Rambam(which is no surprise). However,there is a teshuva from the Rambam which notes that in his times the chachamim would make the bracha,I wonder if the teimanim have mesorah for his teshuvos

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer

Comment: This is really answering my question. My main curiosity is based on the assumption that this is a Birkat Hamitzvah and the mitzvah is on the *chattan*. Possible angles for an answer would be that even in such situations, another can *motzi* someone else or that this isn't a birkat hamitzvah.

Comment: There are those who hold it is a birkas hashevach